# How to prevent auto login after registration in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1.519 and its [Identity UI as a library](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/aspnetcore-2-1-identity-ui/).
The default behaviour of this library is to auto login a user after registration. I want to remove this behaviour because I don't want to allow logins until email confirmations.

So far, I was able to force email confirmation before allowing "manual" logins using a service configuration:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(opt =>
        {
            opt.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            opt.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            opt.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            opt.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true; //This did the trick
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

But this rule seems to be bypassed by auto login triggered by the Registration functionality.

Whereas a possible way to fix this is to inherit and override Registration behaviour from this library, I was wondering if there was some built-in configuration (such as RequireConfirmedEmail showed above) to achieve this. So far, I have found nothing of the like...

Many thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're referring to. There's a project template that will scaffold a lot of code for you - after that, you edit what you don't need. For example, in [this code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#examine-register-1), you could simply remove `await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);`.

Comment: Hi Tieron! Thanks for answering! Indeed I was experimenting with that and was successful, I've just posted an answer explaining how. But, as I say in that answer I'd like to have a built in configuration to do this, since overriding implies having a lot of scaffolded code only to delete 1 line :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: The overhead of the scaffolded code is the primary reason I don't use most of the Identity Framework - most of what it does can be done in a bespoke fashion with less code. In theory, according to the docs, that setting you used is already supposed to prevent logins from unconfirmed emails - might just need to make sure you've used the most recent version for whatever version of .NET you're running.

Comment: I think you are right Tieson, this current behaviour seems wrong and is probably fixed in later versions. I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1.519 and it seems that current stable version is .NET Core 3.1.10 released on 2020-11-10. That would explain why doc says this is already built in. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

As Tieson suggested in question comments, this behaviour seems to have been corrected on later .NET Core versions. As I said in my question, I was using version 2.1.519 while current stable one is 3.1.10 released on 2020-11-10. If you want to avoid all the code overhead that my original answer demanded, it would be wise to update your .NET Core version.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Indeed it is possible to modify Identity Library's code by overriding it. How to do it is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-with-authorization).

Basically, you scaffold the library's code you want to override. Visual Studio provides a suitable way of doing this:

```
Right click your project -> Add -> New Scaffolded Item -> Identity
```

It also helps you select what functionalities you want to override:
[image]
In this case, Account/Register.

This generates all the necessary code for that functionality, inside your Areas folder. Then, all you have to do is go to Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml.cs and modify OnPostAsync method, deleting the SignIn line after the email sending.

Voilá, mission completed. BUT, you got yourself a lot of files and code that you didn't want to, just to delete one single tiny little line...

I still would love to have a built in configuration for this.

Comment: I still encounter this behaviour in .NET Core 5.0.8. Solution for me was to also set `RequireConfirmedAccount` to `true`. Then you get a "a confirmation email will be sent" message after registering, instead of just logging you in.

Answer (score 0):

> I still would love to have a built in configuration for this.

If you compare it with built-in code of `RegisterModel` class in ASP.NET Core 3+, you would find it determine if auto login a user after registration based on configuration value of [`RequireConfirmedAccount` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinoptions?view=aspnetcore-3.0), like below.

```
if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
{
    return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
}
else
{
    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

You can achieve same in your ASP.NET Core 2.1 project by checking the configuration value of `RequireConfirmedEmail` option.

```
if (!_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail)
{
    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
}

return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I still encounter this behaviour in .NET Core 5.0.8.

If you also set `RequireConfirmedAccount` to `true`, you get a "a confirmation email will be sent" message after registering, instead of just logging you in:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
}
```